# Correct adjective for an RV with a Student's $t$-distribution

Tags: terminology, t-distribution

If a variable has a normal distribution, we say it is *normally* distributed. If it has an exponential distribution, we say it is *exponentially* distributed.

What is the proper way to reference a variable with a Student's $t$-distribution?

For example, how would one complete this sentence:
"... and we consider the observations to be <> random variables"?

Comment: _$t$-distributed_ maybe? Hey, the difference in the number of characters between _$t$-distributed_ and _exponentially_ is statistically insignificant!

Comment: @DilipSarwate, shouldn't we be comparing ***t***-*distributed* with *exponentially distributed* instead? The number of characters differs more then.

Comment: @RichardHardy No, _exponentially_ distributed is a misnomer and a waste of characters. We should all be using _$e$-distributed_ and _$n$-distributed_ and _$g$-distributed_ etc in the interest of brevity (and the 600 character limitation on comments enforced by stackexchange etc)......

Comment: ... and why not say _normal_ random variable and _exponential_ random variable and _Rayleigh_ random variable and _Cauchy_ random variable and _Gamma_ random variable instead of the mouthful of "$X$ is a normally distributed random variable" etc?

Comment: @DilipSarwate, fine. Then we should compare ***t***-*distributed* and *exponential* (instead of *exponentially*).

Comment: It isn't even clear to me why it is $t$-distributed, with the hyphen. It isn't "normally-distributed". Additionally, we can have _normal_ variables. But, there are also no $t$ variables (at least, I don't think I've seen that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scortchi's prescriptive answer is very good. From a purely descriptive viewpoint, I have found all of the following on Google scholar, but my conclusion is these forms are *relatively unusual*, particularly when we compare how often a phrasing with "normally distributed" is used instead of "normal distribution" — in comparison to the relatively small numbers found below, there were tens of thousands of results for both "Student's t distribution" and "Student t distribution".

- "Student's t distributed" found 154 papers, including the particular forms (I include a brief snippet for context):

  - [generate a **Student's t distributed** signal](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=4102863) (no hyphen; this variant seems most common)
  - [modelled as an EGARCH(1,2) process with **Student's t-distributed**
    innovations](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1042443104000794) (hyphen between "t" and "distributed"; still fairly common)
  - [the innovations ... are fat- tailed as well, and are **Student's-t distributed**](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jae.3950060306/abstract) (hyphen between "Student's" and "t"; this variant noticeably less common than the other two)
- "Student t distributed" found just over 1,000 papers, though this included many results with "Student's".

  - [a GARCH model under the assumption of **Student-t distributed** errors](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07474938608800095) (hyphen between "Student" and "t"; this variant most common by a clear margin)
  - [the loss L is **Student t distributed**](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/14697680902814225) (no hyphen)
  - [independent **Student t-distributed** random variables](http://iopscience.iop.org/1751-8121/41/26/265004) (hyphen between "t" and "distributed"; this variant fairly rare)
  - [with **Student-t-distributed** innovation](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378426610004541) (hyphens between "Student" and "t" and "distributed"; this variant least common by a clear margin)
- "Student distributed" had about 500 results, of which many were false hits (e.g. "a student distributed the surveys"). So certainly less common than variants of "Student t distributed" but probably at least as common, if not more so, than "Student's t distributed".

  - [This produces returns that are **Student distributed** for intraday time scales](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.3841.pdf) (no hyphen, by far the most common)
  - [The **Student-distributed** random variables were obtained](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610918708812594) (with hyphen, unusual, but note there may be [grammatical reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier) for placing a hyphen in a compound modifier when it appears before the noun phrase it is describing, as in the cited example.)
- "Student's distributed" had just ten results, including false hits for a similar reason as "student distributed" did. There were results both with and without hyphens but the sample size is too small to determine which is more common.

  - [the fractional power change rate (or gradient) is **Student's distributed** with two degrees of freedom](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=820716) (without hyphen)
  - [the **Student's-distributed** factor analyzers](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=4451278) (with hyphen)
- I even turned up 60 papers with "t-Student distributed", for instance ["Simulated sizes of the test for **t-Student
  distributed** errors"](http://www.tandfonline.com/eprint/arEvXHka7BxjrNxtMi3A/full?mobileUi=0), where there was invariably a hyphen between "t" and "Student". This looks odd to me, so I wouldn't recommend it, but it was not particularly rare. I did check and found a fair number of papers using the phrase "t-Student distribution" so perhaps reversing "t" and "Student" is not as unusual as it strikes me (Google Scholar found 2000 hits, compared to 11,000 for "Student's t distribution" and 25,000 for "Student t distribution").

So actual practice varies widely! I think the most common variant I found overall was "Student-t distributed", and if you were to go with this then your usage would not be unusual. Something I found puzzling was how the location of the hyphen is very inconsistent: while "Student's t-distributed" is more common than "Student's-t distributed" (which does look very unnatural), when the "'s" is omitted I found that "Student-t distributed" was massively more common than "Student t-distributed". It seems that people feel a hyphen is needed somewhere, but do not necessarily agree on where it should go. On the other hand, before "distributed" the "Student t" or "Student's t" is acting as an adverb, and style guides generally declare along the lines that "[most adverbial phrases do not need hyphens](http://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-a)".

Comment: (+1, grudgingly). If you were to go with "principle component analysis", your usage wouldn't be unusual: 46,900 hits.

Comment: @Scortchi I thought your answer was stylistically better but my curiosity was piqued as to what forms were "out there". Interestingly pretty much none of these combinations were common enough in the Google Books corpus to show up on Google n-grams. In contrast it is possible to do a decent n-gram of "Student's t distribution" vs "Student t distribution" vs "t-Student distribution" to see trends in their relative prevalence (primarily in textbooks). I'm not convinced that counting papers is a great metric (how many papers does Google index?) but all these forms can be at least be attested.

Comment: (I'll admit to a bias: personally [I'm a descriptivist not a prescriptivist!](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/prescriptivism-and-descriptivism/) I try to follow [Postel's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle): I make an effort to be conservative with adherence to traditional rules in the way I write, but generally liberal in interpreting English written by others. For me, "English" is what people "out there" actually write, rather than what the grammar books say they should. So my answer should be taken in that vein, I'm not suggesting any of these are great style.)

Comment: As for "principle component analysis": should  "principle" and "principal" eventually appear with equal frequency in such settings, then they will have effectively been rendered synonymous. Sad will be the day, for a useful distinction will be lost. Till then, "principle components" is a minority usage, regarded as mistaken by majority users (and hence best avoided if you wish not to be regarded as mistaken). I don't think "a Student-t distributed random variable" is so bad, but writing "a random variable following a Student's t distribution" isn't so clunky either, and sidesteps the issue.

Comment: I subscribe to that mode of thinking about language as well, @Silverfish, which is why I marked this one as "correct", though both answers are great!

Answer (score 3):

"Normal" &  "exponential" are adjectives, already furnished with the adverbs "normally" & "exponentially". When a noun or noun phrase is pressed into service as an adjective there won't in general be a corresponding adverb to hand<sup>†</sup>. So "Weibull distributed" or "gamma distributed", though you sometimes see them, are already doing some violence to grammar (I'd avoid those). "Student's t distributed" seems even worse; I think because the possessive modifier is supposed to apply to the "t distribution", or if not just because it reminds us that "Student's t" is really a noun phrase<sup>‡</sup>. So  don't say that.

"Student's t random variable" seems fine—here "t" is being used attributively, as an adjective; & why not? "Has a Student's t distribution" or "follows a Student's t distribution" are other options.

† Even when we've a proper adjective, like "Gaussian", we're still not guaranteed an adverb. "Gaussianly distributed"? No.

‡ I'm uncertain whether "Student's t distribution" is better parsed as "the t distribution, invented by Student", or "the distribution of Student's t statistic".

Comment: Gosset-_ian_ ... makes you cringe. There's no solution.